# Why does Samson the parrot figure so prominently in the climax of La Fiesta del Chivo?

Tags: spanish-language, vargas-llosa, la-fiesta-del-chivo

In the final chapter of *La Fiesta del Chivo* (*The Feast of the Goat*), Samson the parrot plays a recurring role.  Here are a few examples:

> Her reply is a sudden jabbering.  The five women turn their heads: Samson is awake and announces it by chattering. [...]
>
> Samson, who has been quiet for awhile, displays his pleasure or displeasure again by puffing out his feathers and shrieking.  No one says anything. [...]
>
> Samson has begun to move nervously around the bars of his cage; he sways back and forth, stops, sharpens his beak on his claws.

These short interludes are interspersed in Urania's recounting of her most tightly held secret, but I don't recognize any real pattern.  I suppose it's possible that Vargas Llosa simply wanted a light way to interrupt the story, but I suspect it's more than that.  What is the purpose and/or meaning of Samson's interjections through this crucial part of the story?